# How to create a for loop to iterate up to a variable's value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a for loop to iterate from 1 to the amount of times a variable returns from firebase.

In my database I have the structure:

```
project-id
    featured
        amount: 2
        post1
            postID: postID
            userOfPost: userID
        post2
            postID: postID
            userOfPost: userID
```

The 'amount' variable will dynamically change when a post get added to the 'featured' node. I'm using this 'amount' data to find out how many times I need to iterate the for loop to add each post data to it's own array, like so:

```
post1 = ["postID", "userID"]
post2 = ["postID", "userID"]
```

The code I have so far is:

```
    func getFeaturedPost(){
    var number = 0
    ref.child("featured").child("amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        number = snapshot.value as! Int
        print(number)
    })

    for pos in 1...number+1{ 
        ref.child("featured").child("post\(pos)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postID"] as? String ?? ""
        let userOfPost = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["userOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
        print("postID: \(postID)")
        print("userOfPost: \(userOfPost)")
        })
    }
}
```

At the moment I'm only receiving the first node back (post1). Have I done the for loop correctly or is there a better way of retrieving more than one child's data in Firebase?

Comment: the upper range in a for loop is supposed to be inclusive, why are you adding a `+1`?

Comment: @quant24 since I needed to account for the nodes starting at '1' for instance, it doesn't start at 'post0' it starts at 'post1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run the "fetching post" code after the "fetching number of posts" code has fetched the count. Right now, they are start running almost simultaneously.

Remember that getting data from the Internet takes time, which is why the methods that get data from the Internet usually have a completion handler, which will be called when it's done its job in the background. You should put the for loop inside the completion handler before it. Also, the loop should be `0..<number` because `1...number+1` will loop one more time than needed, and `1...number` will crash if `number` is 0.

```
ref.child("featured").child("amount").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

    number = snapshot.value as! Int
    print(number)


    for pos in 0..<number { 
        ref.child("featured").child("post\(pos + 1)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let postID = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["postID"] as? String ?? ""
        let userOfPost = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["userOfPost"] as? String ?? ""
        print("postID: \(postID)")
        print("userOfPost: \(userOfPost)")
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: That was better than what? @NathanEllis